# How to get tweet id based on an image url contained by the tweet?

Tags: twitter

I have some image urls extracted from tweets and now I need more information contained by the tweets, like text content, user name and mentions. I think it should be helpful if I can get the tweet id based on the image url. 
So is there anyway I can achieve this goal? In other words, is there any specific conversion rules between image url and tweet id in Twitter?

image url segment: D2eNxz8WsAAWhKT
corresponding tweet id: 1110011728824283136
I have tried 64 binary system, but it did not work.

Comment: If you have the image URL you can search it on Google Images

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no connection. Images are uploaded independently of Tweets, and are associated with Tweets later. There is no rule that connects Tweet and Media IDs on Twitter.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Andy.